# Best Ubuntu 12.10 janitor program

Tags: 12.10

What is the best janitor program for ubuntu 12.10, I been using ubuntu tweaks but as far as I know they stopped development on this program any good alternative

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ubuntu Tweak will continue development, there was so much feed back that the developer decided to continue it.
See [Here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/ubuntu-tweak-development-stopped.html) for webupd8.org's post on it  and [Here](http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2012/10/22/thank-you-ubuntu-tweak-will-continue.html) for the developers blog post.

[Computer Janitor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/computer-janitor-gtk/) was the default program and was removed in 12.04 but can still be found in the Software Center and installed if for some reason Ubuntu Tweak stops development again in the future.

UPDATE: On the [developers blog page](http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/donate)  there is a link to donate to project development via Paypal.  I too think that this is one of the must have apps for the Untiy DE so I think I will be sending some money myself to help insure that the project will be able to continue.

Comment: @Levan glad I was able to help.  I found a donation page and updated my answer in case your interested.

Answer (score 6):

I find Bleachbit to be the most comprehensive system cleaner.

Comment: Bleachbit is very thorough. You might want to make sure before you hit delete. It is a very good app.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the tools that others have mentioned, a great cleaning tool is [Mundus Home Folder Cleaner](http://blog.mundusproject.org/) (the name says it all)